# How to convert image or text file to byte array in Perl?

Tags: perl

How to convert image, text, PDF or for that instance any file to byte array in Perl, without using any external library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [open](http://p3rl.org/open) to open the file, specify the `:raw` to read it in binary. [read](http://p3rl.org/read) (or any other means) reads into a buffer, so you need to [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) it into bytes.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name = shift;

my @byte_array;
open my $fh, '<:raw', $file_name or die $!;
while (read $fh, my $buffer, 16384) {
        push @byte_array, unpack 'c*', $buffer;
}
print 'Size: ', scalar @byte_array, "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. I am trying to work with it.
Wanted to ask what is number `16384`  ? How should it vary?

Comment: Try experimenting with it to find the fastest way.